# ffmpeg error on DVCPRO HD encoding is not supported

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe, video-codecs, .mov

Please help, I'm trying to encode a video stream, and output the video using the same format as my input:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v dvvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p -b:v 115084915 -maxrate 115084915 -minrate 115084915 -r 29.97 -top 1 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -vtag dvh6 -c:a copy -c:s copy -y output.mov
```

this is the output:

```
DVCPRO HD encoding is not supported.\n[dvvideo @ 0x7ffaee815c00] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed\nError initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height\nConversion failed!\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an older version of ffmpeg.

In a recent version, the following combinations are supported by the DV encoder:

```
 Frame size: 720x480; pixel format: yuv411p, framerate: 30000/1001     
 Frame size: 720x576; pixel format: yuv420p, framerate: 25/1           
 Frame size: 720x576; pixel format: yuv411p, framerate: 25/1           
 Frame size: 720x480; pixel format: yuv422p, framerate: 30000/1001     
 Frame size: 720x576; pixel format: yuv422p, framerate: 25/1           
 Frame size: 1280x1080; pixel format: yuv422p, framerate: 30000/1001   
 Frame size: 1440x1080; pixel format: yuv422p, framerate: 25/1         
 Frame size: 960x720; pixel format: yuv422p, framerate: 60000/1001     
 Frame size: 960x720; pixel format: yuv422p, framerate: 50/1           
 Frame size: 720x576; pixel format: yuv420p, framerate: 25/1
```

Comment: Gyan, thank you so much. I did trust you know what you're suggesting, I had to recompile a lot of code in addition to FFMPEG, and this took me over 2 days to finish this. The result is that it now works, and I'm super happy about the time invested.